# Прежде чем вернуться на страницу с деталки обратно в каталог, происходит скролл

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Столкнулась со следующей проблемой: есть страница каталога с карточками товара. Перед возвратом с карточки товара обратно в каталог, происходит скролл на странице товара ровно на столько, на сколько перед этим пролистали в каталоге, прежде чем перейти в деталку. В проекте нет никаких перехватчиков. Проблема возникает и по router.back (next) и по браузерному popstate.
Т.е.: в каталоге выбрали товар -> перешли к товару -> кликаем на кнопку назад по роутеру или через браузер -> нынешняя страница в этот момент скроллит вниз на столько, на сколько мы изначально наскроллили в каталоге -> и только потом возвращает к каталогу в начало